# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'WHILE' (Snowflake SQL)

Tags: sql, while-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run while loop in snowflake but its throwing error on first line which is on "While"

Error msg :- SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'WHILE'.

Sample code as below :-

```
        WHILE ((SELECT Max(Column1) FROM table1) IS NOT NULL AND (SELECT Max(Column2) FROM table1) IS NOT NULL)
        DO
        
        UPDATE table 2
    set Column1(from table 1) = select col1 from table2...
        ....... (some more logic)
---column1(this value will be updated for while condition)
        ;
        
        insert into table 2
        ....(Some logic) --> 
        ;
        END WHILE;
```

The below statement  :-

```
SELECT Max(Column1) FROM table1 and SELECT Max(Column2) FROM table1
 -->
```

Will intially hold 0 and 0 as the value and then from update query it will fetch the data for which it will run the loop

can anyone help with whats the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake requires that you write such code in Scripting Blocks. Try to pack your code in

```
BEGIN
...
END
```

Doc: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/blocks#using-an-anonymous-block